# Data logging not happening with required rate using CSV library for python

Tags: python, csv

This is my first question her.

I am trying to build a code to log MQTT messages to a .csv file. Earlier we did this using " >> filename.csv" in the terminal. But since i want to add copying the files to a remote server with a single command, I have written the following code and is working.

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqttClient 
import csv




def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    global recieved_data
    recieved_data = str(message.payload.decode("utf-8"))
    print("message received " ,recieved_data)
    csv_writer.writerow([recieved_data])
    my_data_file.flush()   
  

hostname = input ("Enter host IP : ")
topic_name = input("Enter topic name : ")
file_name = input ("Enter file name : ")

client = mqttClient.Client("Python_1")    
client.connect(hostname)
client.loop_start()
client.subscribe(topic_name)                  #Topic name



my_data_file = open(file_name, 'w')
csv_writer = csv.writer(my_data_file, delimiter=',')



while True:
 client.on_message = on_message
```

But the code is not able to capture all the data at the rate at which the messages are being published. I verified it by comparing the values with the file generated from the following  -

```
mosquitto_sub -h "Hostname" -t "Topic_name" >> filename.csv
```

When I compare the data, I am missing almost half the messages logged using the first method. When I removed CSV part then I get the required rate of logging.

Can someone suggest a way to log the recieved messages at the required rate??

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to do this is a faster way. I have used the subprocess module to execute the following command which would save the outputs of stdout to a .txt file.

`$ mosquitto_sub -t "topic_name" >> filename.txt`

The following code does this.

```
import subprocess
import os

filename = input ("Enter file name : ")
topic_name = input ("Enter topic name: ")

with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    a = subprocess.Popen(["mosquitto_sub", "-t",topic_name],stdout = f )  #Start logging messages
```

Not sure if this is a good way to go about it, but observed a significant increase in the logging rate (I am publishing a dummy message at 100 Hz). However still the rate is slower as all the messages which I have published hasn't been written to the file.

Is there any way to make sure the rate of logging can be matched?